# Styling the selectTable header in react-table

Tags: javascript, react-table

Using the selectTable option out of the react-table component, we've figured out how to style each header's column with headerStyle that we're generating but can't figure out how to style the actual select toggle (first) column that contains the toggle checkbox.

Can't seem to find anything in the documentation that would indicate how to do this.

Comment: so I am also have this problem, solved it by not using SelectTable but implement select function myself.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering but if your issue is not related to this then Can you explain the issue with your code?

```
    columns={[

        {
           accessor: 'myAcc',
           Header: //any jsx or string here,
           getProps: () => getProps(redCell), // return CSS
           Cell: (rowInfo): JSX.Element => //you can render your jsx for the cell. 
        },
   ]}
```

Comment: The questioner is using a <SelectTable> of react-table, so it will automatically add a checkbox colum at the first of table (so you don't has the access to that column via the columns configuration array)